# How to understand 美人只配强者拥有?

Tags: grammar

I know its meaning. But I can't understand it in grammar.
And does that means when it becomes an adage or 梗, we don't need to care about the grammar?

Comment: In my humble opinion, it might come from some video game.

Comment: After looked up, It seems to come from little pupil students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "美人只配(被)强者拥有" is  a [(topic) + (comment/ opinion)] sentence.
>
> (*this phrase diminish the value of beauties*)

**It is not an adage**

- Topic: 美人 (beautiful women)
- Comment: 只配被强者拥有 (only worthy of being owned by the strong ones)

美人 (beautiful women)

只配 (only worthy of)

*被(by) omitted*

强者(the strong one)

拥有 (to own)

The sentence above means "Beautiful women only deserve to be owned by the strong ones"

**Substitute the topic and comment**:

> 木棒只配給材民作武器
>
> Topic: 木棒 (Wooden stick)
>
> Comment: 只配給村民作武器 (only worthy of used as weapon by villagers)

~

> 聖劍只有英雄才配揮舞
>
> Topic: :聖劍 (Holy sword)
>
> Comment: 只有英雄才配揮舞 (only hero deserve to swing it)

"美人只配(被)强者拥有" is different from "只有强者才配拥有美人" (only the strong ones deserve to own beautiful women). Which is a [SVO] sentence

> 只有强者才配拥有美人 (only the strong ones deserve  to own beautiful women)
>
> (*this phrase elevate the status of the strong ones*)

[S] = 强者 (the strong ones)

[V] = 拥有 (own)

[O] = 美人 (beautiful women)

*只有 ~ 才 ~ is a conjunction  (only)*

*配 (worthy of) is an adverb for the verb 拥有 (own)*

Answer (score 3):

It is not an adage. It is a correct sentence.
配 originally means "match", derived for meaning "deserve".
Therefore, this sentence should be a passive sentence meaning: "Beauties should only be deserved by the strongs to own" (literally, word-to-word) or "Only the strongs deserve beauties" (native).

Comment: The sentence in OP's post means "Beauties only  deserve to be own by the strongs "  It is different from  "Only the strongs deserve beauties"  the first one stating "Beauties is not worth anything other than be owned by heroes " and the second one means " Only hero is worthy of owning beauties, no one else does"

Comment: 美人只应被强者拥 (beauties should only be owned by the strongs) would match  "Only the strongs deserve beauties" better

Answer (score 0):

> "美人只配强者拥有"

I have a different opinion about the sentence here.  If you think deep, it doesn't seem to be logical. Usually, 只配 is used in a active voice, as in 你只配给我提鞋. Used in a passive is a bit odd in my opinion.

However, if I heard it, I would think it means the same as 只有强者才配拥有美人.